# Как заполнить поле связной модели Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу в модель ResultTest запоминать результаты выполненных тестов для каждого пользователя и заменять их в случае перерешивания теста, как передать номер теста в ResultTest, я понимаю что нужно создать в модели ResultTest что то вроде этого test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE), но как это заполнять из views.py

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True) # (null=True,blank=True) показываем что это необязательный аргумент
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self): # имя в админ панели
        return f'№{self.number} '


class Test(models.Model):
    number_test = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    task = models.ManyToManyField('Task', related_name='tasks')

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.number_test}'

class ResultTest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.IntegerField('res', default=False)
```

views.py

```
...
@login_required()
def answer(request, pk):
    ...
    user = request.user
    new = ResultTest(result=res, user = user)
    new.save()

    context = {
                'a': a,
                'pk': pk,
                'res': res
                }

    return render(request, '/answer.html', context )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых задайте для модели Test колонку с уникальным значением, то есть значением по которому вы сможете определить уникальность теста, импортируйте в views модель Test, и точно также как вы заносите в RequestTest поля user и result, найдите Тест по его айди

```
test = Test.objects.get(id=<int>)
```

И положите его в ваш ForeignKey у RequestTest.

Comment: То есть, если у меня уникальный тест задается  полем number_test, а внутри функции answer, уникальность отвечает pk, то все должно выглядеть примерно так.
test = Test.objects.get(number_test=pk)
 user = request.user
    new = ResultTest(result=res, user = user, test = test)
    new.save()

    context = {
                'a': a,
                'pk': pk,
                'res': res
                'test': test,
                }

    return render(request, '/answer.html', context )

а в модели :
class ResultTest(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, ...)

Comment: Да, попробуйте так.

Comment: Работает, появилось связное поле, но результат тот же, он на каждое прохождение теста добавляет новую запись в БД, а не перезаписывает старую, что в принципе неудивительно , как организовать проверку если запись по этому id  что бы я мог перезаписать и как перезаписать, а иначе буду создавать если не нашлось, не подскажите?

Comment: Сделайте проверку на прохождение, что то типа if RequestTest.objects.get('условия вашего поиска') , если пользователь проходил тест то просто вытаскиваете все данные из request и ставите их вместо своих. Насколько я понимаю у вас тесты в виде формы ? Если да то попробуйте сделать так как я сказал. А вообще поищите в документации информацию про Классовые представления. Есть класс UpdateView который почти все делает за вас.